# Pseudo class :active, Bug in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, effect

The example is : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzrdmo

I don't understand when I apply the click effect with `:active` pseudoclass on icon ( tag) inside div on firefox, when I unclick the div, it keeps clicked...

I see that when I remove the relative position in pseudoclass `:active`, this works fine but without effect...
This problem only occurs in firefox... in chrome, safari, etc works fine.
someone knows why?

Thanks.

**EDIT: The Fix for this question is explained in the first answer.
"but if you also add position: relative (without a top setting) to the hover state rule, this fixes the problem" - @Johannes
thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:active` is the state while - after clicking a link - the browser still displays the old page, but already tries to load and open the new one / the target page. Usually, unless the loading of the new page takes long, this time interval is so short that you'll hardly see it, which is the reason that very often the `active` state gets the same CSS as `hover` - not making a visual difference between them..

In your example, source and target page are the same - it's a some-page link. Obviously different browsers handle that differently, concerning the `active` status. Some interpret the link as "new page loaded", others as "still on the old page" (and therefore still active)...

Comment: okey.. I understant these reason but Why when I remove the position property on CSS style, It's work fine but when the position relative is yet, the handle is worn again.

This only happens on in firefox

Comment: I am not completely sure either, but if you also add `position: relative` (without a `top` setting) to the `hover` state rule, this fixes the problem - HTH

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awNxpb yes! this fix the problem... I don't understand why.. but is a solution jajaja Thanks
PD: this question was only for curiosity, why need this fix when in the other browsers isn't necessary?